# To prove the inequality

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

$${n \choose 0}+{n \choose 3}+{n \choose 6}+\cdots+{n \choose 3k}\le \dfrac13(2^n+2)$$
Where $3k\le n$

It looks similar to the expansion of $2^n$ and since every three terms is missing 2 so the inequality will the one-third. I get this by intuition, but I am stuck and cannot approach the problem. Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

let $$f(x)=(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k$$
then
$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n}{3k}=\dfrac{1}{3}[f(1)+f(w)+f(w^2)]=\dfrac{1}{3}[2^n+(-1)^nw^{2n}+(-1)^nw^n]$$
where $w^3=1$

Answer (score 1):

If you sum all terms up to $k = \dfrac{n}{3}$, the result is $\dfrac{(2^n+2cos(n \dfrac{\Pi}{3}))}{3}$ which is smaller than the RHS.

Comment: please elaborate your answers sir, I could not understand the direct step.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case of things I learnt when young (loooong time ago) as so called "remarkable identities" in combinatorics. I suppose I shall not be able anymore to establish them; I take the results from my notes.

For s(k) = Sum[Binomial[n,i k,{i,0,n/k}],we were shown that the results were successively

s(1) = 2^n
s(2) = 2^(n - 1)
s(3) = (2^n + 2 Cos[n Pi / 3]) / 3
s(4) = 2^(n - 2) + 2^(n / 2 - 1) Cos[n Pi / 4]

Above k=5,we were told that the formulas become quite complex. So my memory stopped at that point. I always accepted that, ignoring that it could be of any use at any time.

Please sure I am sorry not to be able to provide more.

Comment: Thank you anyway sir, I atleast have a lead...I will try to dig out any information if available!